# How do you link to a specific part of a page in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically creating some buttons in jQM, like this:

```
return '<a href="#glossary" id="' + match + '" class="glossaryLink" data-transition="slide">' + match + '</a>';
```

This works fine for creating the buttons - they have the same `id` as the text on the button and they link fine to the glossary page.

What I need to do is link to the specific *place* in the glossary page.

Now normally you'd do

```
<a href="glossary.html#' +match+ '">
```

But in jQM I'd have to do

```
<a href="#glossary#' + match + '">
```

and this doesn't seem to work. I creates an `href` with `#glossary#target` which doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution, is to add a custom attribute to *Anchor*, e.g. `data-subpage="#sectionOne"`, and store that value in a *variable* to retrieve value later when you change to `glossary` page.

```
<a href="#glossary" data-subpage="#sectionTwo" class="ui-btn subpage">Section two</a>
```

In `#glossary` page, add `id` attribute to sectioin div matching `data-subpage` in link but without hash `#`.

```
<div data-role="page" id="glossary">
  <div id="sectionOne">
    <p>Section one</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bind click event on *Anchors* with class `subPage` using `pagecreate`. Once clicked, store `data-subpage` value in a *global variable*.

```
var subPage;

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
    $(".subpage").on("click", function () {
        subPage = $(this).data("subpage");
    });
});
```

Once you have the value of *subpage* stored, you need to listen to `pagecontainershow` in order to scroll to a div with `id` stored in *subPage* variable.

You need first to defined whether the active page is `glossary` or not using `getActivePage`. Also, check that `subPage` variable is neither `null` nor `undefined`. Otherwise, the page will open normally.

If active page is `glossary` and `subPage` is defined, retrieve `.offset().top` of that div and the scroll to it either with animation or without animation.

Moreover, note that you need to `setTimeout` to run scroll function to make sure that page is fully loaded and *transition* is done.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;
    if ( !! subPage && activePage == "glossary") {
        var scrollTo = $(subPage).offset().top;
        setTimeout(function () {
            /* $.mobile.silentScroll(scrollTo); without animation */
            $("body").animate({
                scrollTop: scrollTo

            }, 500, function () { /* 500ms animation speed - it's up to you */
                subPage = null; /* reset variable */
            });
        }, 300); /* scroll after 300ms - it's up to you */
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LJzHG/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1)</sup> Tested on iPhone 5 - Safari Mobile

Comment: Doesn't this need a jQM plugin for sub pages and isn't there an easier solution? This just won't mesh with my other code as the glossary links are created dynamically - the text is put through a function with adds the anchors around any text that matches the glossary database. I don't want or need scroll animations - just getting to the info is all that is required.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect I understood that you want user to reach a specific part within `glossary` page, right? why do you need a plugin when you can achieve it in some JS lines? if you dont want animation, then use `$.mobile.silentScroll()`.

Comment: @Omar Don't you need a plugin for data-subpage to work? If not, I'll try it again. I tried using your code but it didn't work.

Comment: [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) is HTML5, it doesn't require any plugin. Maybe you need to tweak my code to get aligned with yours. let me know if you need further assistance @SubjectiveEffect

Comment: Okay, I've added your exact code and it just links like normal - just to glossary. I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined "

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect you should add `id` to _sections_ in glossary page. Sorry, I forgot to mention this in my answer. `id` should be equal to `data-subpage`.

Comment: Okay, I changed #pageID to #glossary and to the page that the link is on. If it's #glossary I don't get that error, but it doesn't go the part in the glossary that I need. If it's the page that the links are on then I do get that error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50054/discussion-between-omar-and-subjective-effect)