# How to scroll to Anchor when displaying a page in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile and I have a big page which consists of two(or more) parts.

I hope to let the user view the second part when displaying my page for some case.

How can I achieve that? Can I do this to provide a special URL with some specific id?

**Please note:** I only need a URL, since I will post this URL to my user in some client, and the url should determine which part to show.

I use open my html file with :`E:path\....\rule.html#zhuaguirule`. This does not work to scroll to that desired part, but when I hit enter again from the browser, it works. I do not know why this is happening or how to solve this.

```
<div data-role="page" id="rule">
    <div data-role="content" id="wodirule">  <!--this is one part-->
     <h2>PART1</h2>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li>....</li>
            <li>....</li>
        </ul>
     </div>  
     <br><br>    

    <div data-role="content" id="zhuaguirule"><!--this is the other part-->
    <h2>PART2</h2>  
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li>....</li>
                <li>....</li>                   
            </ul>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>

    </div>

   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="1.html" data-icon="home">....</a></li>
            <li><a href="2.html" data-icon="home">....</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22492387/1771795

Comment: @Omar, Thank you! But the solution is not completely what I want, I just need a URL, which will be given to my user outside the jquery mobile. So, do I have a way to achieve that?

Comment: You mean you want to retrieve hash in URL?

Comment: Not, hash, I just want something maybe like: http.....html#parts_id  , but this is not working when I enter it in my pc browser and type ENTER. But it works when I type enter again.

Comment: I'm still unable to understand you question. What do you want to achieve exactly? show/hide div's based on #hash in url?

Comment: @Omar ,Lets say I have 10 game rules in my page of "page". And all of the rules is display in the list<UL>. For some case, I hope to give my user a URL and this url can bring them in to rule#5. Some will bring to rule#4. I believe this is called "anchor". But it is not working in my jquery mobile page, until I press the second enter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60003/discussion-between-omar-and-jaskey).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60024/discussion-between-jaskey-and-omar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of jQuery Mobile upon loading a page or changing between pages, is that it scrolls/jumps to the top. This is actually a fix for mobile browsers, where address bar hides part of *header*.

The below solutions overrides jQuery Mobile's default behavior by scrolling to target div when page is fully shown.

#### jQuery Mobile <= 1.3

You have two solutions. Use them on `pagechange` event.

1. Override `$.mobile.defaultHomeScroll`; by default it returns `0`. Retrieve `hash` from `window.location`, find `.offset().top` of the target div and then scroll to it.

   ```
   $(document).on("pagechange", function () {
       var section = location.hash ? location.hash : null;
       if (section != null) {
           var activePage = $.mobile.activePage;
           $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll = activePage.find(section).offset().top;
       }
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yp3ydos7/show/#five)**
2. If you want animation, use `.animate()` instead of override `$.mobile.defaultHomeScroll`.

   ```
   $(document).on("pagechange", function () {
       var section = location.hash,
           activePage = $.mobile.activePage;
       if (section) {
           var scrollTo = activePage.find(section).offset().top;
           setTimeout(function () {
               $("body").animate({
                   scrollTop: scrollTo
               }, 500, function () {
                   subPage = null;
               });
           }, 500);
       }
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qLo0y6b3/show/#six)**

---

#### jQuery Mobile >= 1.4

Replace

- `pagechange` with `pagecontainershow` or `pagecontainertransition`.
- `$.mobile.activePage` with `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");`.

> **Demo**: [Solution 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sspLtn3q/show/#two) - [Solution 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dt79xx1e/show/#three)

Comment: Thank you! I copy your first part into my code within the <head><script>  ....</script></head>. But the same, I do not know if I should change any thing for that? I am new to jquery

Comment: @Jaskey if you're using _single page model_ (each page in a different file) you need to either load it on `head` or in `body` of the target page. But in this case, you need to bind `pagechange` to a specific page. For `pagecontainershow`, you have to check if the event is emitted on the target page not different page.

Comment: I changed my <script src> into the head. And now it is working. Would you please also explain why We should override the functions to make the anchor works since the anchor should be working without any js in html, so that I can accept your answer. Thank you!