# jquery mobile multi-page internal hyperlinking

Tags: jquery-mobile, hyperlink, internal, multipage

This appears to be pretty basic but I can't figure it out.

Using a jqm multipage template, I'm trying to allow users to jump from a link one page (id='page1') directly to an image in another page (id='page2').

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmqedzb0/)

It appears I am constrained, by html hyperlinking rules and jqm, to this:

```
<a href='#page2'>go to image on p2</a>
```

... which of course jumps the user to the top of page2.

But that's not what I want. I want the user to jump directly to the IMAGE, which is close to the bottom of page2, tagged like so:

```
<img id='image-id'>
```

But tagging the link with the image's id (not the page's id), i.e. tagging it like this

```
<a href='#image-id'>go to image on p2</a>
```

doesn't work.

I get the feeling I'm missing something very obvious, but can't figure it out.

Any suggestions? Or is this not possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22492387/1771795

Answer (score 0):

I've got a different problem but found this question in my travels... thought I would add an extract from the jquery mobile page:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

> Note: You cannot link to a multipage document with Ajax navigation active because the framework will only load the first page it finds, not the full set of internal pages. In these cases, you must link without Ajax (see next section) for a full page refresh to prevent potential hash collisions. There is currently a [subpage plugin](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget) that makes it possible to load in multi-page documents.